# How to add radio button to radio group in Xamarin for Android via code behind?

Tags: xamarin.android

The title already describes what I want to do: I'm working with Xamarin for Android. Now I'd like to have a `RadioGroup` and fill it with `RadioButton`s via code behind and not via XAML. How can I do this? I don't find any setter...

Why do I need this? My small Android app has a *Load* button which loads entries from a web service. Each entry should be represented by a `RadioButton` so that the user has a flexible selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example I put together for you that creates the Radio Group and Radio Buttons dynamically along with how to determine which button is selected by the user at run-time.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    var layout = new LinearLayout(this) {
        Orientation = Orientation.Vertical
    };

    // Create Radio Group
    var rg = new RadioGroup(this);
    layout.AddView(rg);

    // Add Radio Buttons to Radio Group
    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        var rb = new RadioButton(this) { Text = $"Radio Button {i}" };
        rg.AddView(rb);
    }

    // Show Radio Button Selected
    lblOutput = new TextView(this);
    layout.AddView(lblOutput);
    rg.CheckedChange += (s, e) => {
        lblOutput.Text = $"Radio Button {e.CheckedId} Selected";
    };

    SetContentView(layout);
}
```

**Output**

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, I've implemented a solution using a `ListView`:

```cs
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

    var toolbar = FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
    SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Speakers = new List<ISpeaker>();
    FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.loadButton).Click += LoadButtonOnClick;
}

private async void LoadButtonOnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Speakers = await LoadSpeakersAsync();

    var sourceListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.sourceListView);
    sourceListView.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ISpeaker>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, Speakers);
}
```